# Enabling users to copy-paste from HTML, div introduces line break

Tags: html, gwt, copy-paste

I'm writing a chat application in GWT and have run into the following problem: chat messages are fairly complex, so I'm stringing them together from several elements, forming a `Composite`. This in itself is fine, except the main `Composite` contains a second `Composite` in it, which is a `FlowPanel`, which becomes a `div`; this would normally create a line break.

Now in the website itself, there is no problem, because I can set CSS to display inline. The problem is, I want users to be able to highlight the text and copy-paste it to a regular text editor/notepad application, and when I do that, the line breaks come back.

So for example:

```
<div><div>Name</div>: Message</div>
```

displays on the web page as

```
Name: Message
```

but when I copy-paste it, it becomes

```
Name
: Message
```

instead.

Is there any way to solve this issue? I can't use only inline elements (the name part contains an image), so that sadly can't work.

Comment: please show the thing you've tried with image :)

Comment: Added jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8WQC6 - try copying and pasting the result text into a text editor and you'll see what he means

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I wasn't aware of this tool. Sadly it doesn't work, if you copy the text from the "result" frame into a text editor, it's broken at the :. However, if you change the inner `div` to `span`, it works, but I'm not sure I can do that in my GWT.